# How does the android build system handle java libraries which load native shared libraries

Tags: java, android, native

Consider the following situation: I have two android projects named P1 and P2 which both produce an apk which use the same process-id and will run in the same process on android.
P1 and P2 both use Java library JL1. JL1 loads at runtime shared library1 SL1.

What I see runtime is that at some point I get a java/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError while loading this SL1.
It also outputs: Shared lib  already opened.

What causes this problem? I'm assuming that library code in java is sort of copied in every project/apk and at runtime when apks are merged in one process it forgets about the copies. So every copy loads its shared library itself, causing the already loaded error.

If so, isn't this unwanted behaviour. Because, now you can never have a java library with an shared library in the same process used more than once.

[edit] I found out that every apk uses its own class loader (also when in the same process). This means that every JL will be class loaded per apk and therefore every shared object will be loaded more than once, resulting in an error. Somebody any ideas how to get around this? Is it possible to let apks share a classloader?

Comment: Looks to me like your P1 and P2 get loaded by different class loaders. Could you confirm that? If this is indeed the case, AFAIK this is the expected behavior, i.e.: "The same JNI native library cannot be loaded into more than one class loader." http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jni/jni-12.html  One workaround would be to design your classes such that only one set of them need to access the native methods...

Comment: I think I have to find out. I don't know how android handles this. I think you are rigth. As explained in the question. I use two different apks which are loaded in the same process. I can imagine that android will instantiate one class loader for every apk. It would be better if creates a class loader for every process. Have to look up how android handles this.

Comment: I looked it up. Every apk has its own classloader. So this means the shared object will be loaded twice. Any ideas to fix this?

Comment: I will conclude this question with my own anser and will post another to stackoverflow containing the information about the classloader specifics.

Comment: Sorry for the delay... well if that answers your question, great! I guess :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every apk has its own class loader. This means that two projects/apks will have there own copy of classes from the library. Which they load at runtime. Therefore what looks like the same classes are actually copies. Therefore loading a native library in such a class will result in loading it for every loaded class (even if this is done in the static field). Which results in a runtime error for loading the native shared object more than once if the two apks share the same process.